# Passing returned Java list to webview Javascript as an array in Android

Tags: javascript, java, android, arrays, webview

I'm making an app launcher with a Webview component and I'm trying to pass the list of apps I've got from Package manager into an array in the Javascript in the webview. Doing so with a Javascript interface. I've been able to pass ints into a javascript int variable this way, and when I press the button in the Webview to load the int as a 'p' element, it displays the int as a 'p' element fine, as I expected, but when I try to call the same function from the button to display the list instead of the int, it gives the error 'method not found' referring to the button trying to call getUserInstalledApplications(). Furthermore, the button is simply producing a null message. Here's the Java:

```
    public class webViewInterface {
```

// allows for passing variable values to javascript int he webview

```
    Context mContext;
    webViewInterface(Context c) {
        mContext = c;
    }
    @JavascriptInterface
    public List<ApplicationInfo> getUserInstalledApplications(Context context) {
        // Get installed applications
        final PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        List<ApplicationInfo> installedApplications =
                packageManager.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);

        // Remove system apps
        Iterator<ApplicationInfo> it = installedApplications.iterator();
        while (it.hasNext()) {
            ApplicationInfo appInfo = it.next();
            if ((appInfo.flags & ApplicationInfo.FLAG_SYSTEM) != 0) {
                it.remove();
            }
        }

        // Return installed applications
        return installedApplications;
    }
```

And the Javascript:

```
<div id="loadApps">
<button id="ShowApps" onClick="showAppList()">Show Apps</button>
<script type="text/javascript">
//var numberOfApps = null;
var listOfApps = null;
 function getFromAndroid(){
    listOfApps = MainActivityInterface.getUserInstalledApplications();
 }
 getFromAndroid();
 function showAppList(){
 // create node
 var appP = document.createElement("p");
 var t = document.createTextNode(listOfApps);
 appP.appendChild(t);                                          
 document.body.appendChild(appP);   
}
```